# Android - Not able to to perform onItemClick at a Listview item with ImageButton

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've made the next xml layout for listview item -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back_item"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_bot"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tv_ico" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_saying"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="blah blah"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_nar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="sport"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_clicks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#696969"
                android:text="Clicks"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add_item"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_state"
            android:focusable="false" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Well, when I'm using this xml layout and pressing  on a listview item all is fine - the code gets into the onItemClick.

But when I adding to this layout an ImageButton I'm not able to get into the onItemClick function.

Here's the full layout code with the ImageButton -

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_item"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_bot"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tv_ico" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_saying"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="blah blah"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_nar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="sport"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_clicks"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#696969"
                    android:text="Clicks"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_add_item"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_state"
                android:focusable="false" />
   <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/clip_ico" 
            android:focusable="false"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I've used `android:focusable="false"` but still not able to get into the onItemClick.

Any ideas why it happens?

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`  in the root layout

Comment: When you say 'root layout' do you mean to the first LinearLayout at the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

if you are suing custom Adpter for Listview 
then 
do it in you customadapter - getView method

ImageView YOURIMAGE=(ImageView) InflatedVIEW.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

YOURIMAGE.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override`
            public void onClick(View v) {

}

Comment: This is a layout xml problem not a code one - but thanks for trying to help